# Is there a Radon-Nikodym derivative of a L^2-valued vector measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, radon-nikodym

Let $\Omega$ be a measurable space and $X$ a separable dual Banach space. $X$ is known to have the Radon-Nikodym property: If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-additive measure with range in $X$ and $\nu$ a $\sigma$-additive measure with range in $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\mu<<\nu$, then there exists some $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}:\Omega\rightarrow X$ such that $\mu(E)=\int_E\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}d\nu$ (see theorem III.3.1 in "vector measures" by Diestel and Uhl).

I have an example that seem to contradict this result and I do not understand how:

Define $\Omega=[0,1],\ X=X^*=L^2[0,1],\ \mu(A)=\chi_A\ \forall A\subset\Omega$ the indicator function of $A$ (1 in $A$ and $0$ outside $A$) and $\nu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$.

If $\nu(A)=0$ then $\|\mu(A)\|_{L^2}=(\int_0^1|\chi_A|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\nu(A)^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$ so $\mu<<\nu$. But I do not think there exists $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}:\Omega\rightarrow X$, is there?

- Why I think there is not: Assume there exists some
  $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}:\Omega\rightarrow X$ such that
  $\mu(E)=\int_E\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}d\nu$ then for any $f\in X=X^*$ and
  $E\subset\Omega$:

  $$\int_Ef(\omega)d\omega=\left\langle\mu(E),f\right\rangle_{L^2}=\int_E\left\langle\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(\omega),f\right\rangle_{L^2}d\omega=\int_E\int_{\Omega}\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(\omega)(t)f(t)dtd\omega$$

  which implies
  $$\int_{\Omega}fd\delta_{\omega}=f(\omega)=\int_{\Omega}\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(\omega)(t)f(t)dt$$ for all $f\in X$ and almost every $\omega\in\Omega$ which means 
  $\delta_{\omega}<<\nu$ which is not possible.

Comment: @copper.hat: $\mu$ is supposed to be a vector-valued measure, here taking values in the space $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: So, for $\phi \in (L^2)^*$, we have $\phi ( \mu (A)) = \int_A \phi$? (identifying the dual here)?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Join my gang :-).

Comment: Are you using different $\sigma$-algebras for $\mu$ and $\nu$ - the Lebesgue algebra for $\mu$ and the full subset algebra for $\nu$?

Comment: An idea: Take a basis $\{b_\alpha\}$ for $L^2(\Omega)$ and let $\mu_\alpha(A)$ be the coefficient of $\mu(A)$ for $b_\alpha$. Then each $\mu_\alpha$ is a signed measure and there exists a function $\phi_\alpha$ such that $d\mu_\alpha = \phi_\alpha \, d\nu$. Thus $\phi = \sum_\alpha \phi_\alpha \, b_\alpha$ should satisfy $d\mu = \phi \, d\nu.$ But is $\phi$ a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've left out a key phrase in your statement of the Radon-Nikodym property.  What is true is that if $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-additive measure **of bounded variation** with range in $X$ and $\nu$ a $\sigma$-additive measure with range in $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\mu<<\nu$, then there exists some $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}:\Omega\rightarrow X$ such that $\mu(E)=\int_E\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}d\nu$.  (Check definition III.1.3 of Diestel and Uhl.)

Your measure $\mu$ does not have bounded variation.  Indeed, fix $n$ and let $A_i = [(i-1)/n, i/n) \subset [0,1]$, $i=1,\dots, n$.  Then $\|\mu(A_i)\|_{L^2} = n^{-1/2}$ for each $i$, so $\sum_{i=1}^n \|\mu(A_i)\| = n^{1/2}$, and the variation of $\mu$ is thus at least $n^{1/2}$; but $n$ was arbitrary.

Comment: [Folland](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Modern-Techniques-Applications/dp/0471317160) doesn't require bounded variation, only $\sigma$-finiteness of both measures. The measures are real-valued, however.

Comment: @md2perpe: Well, I would think the correct generalization of $\sigma$-finite for a vector measure should be to require that we can write $\Omega = \bigcup_n \Omega_n$ where $\mu$ is of bounded variation on each $\Omega_n$.  The measure in this example doesn't satisfy that, either.